# ListView in android is not highlighting the row i am selecting

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

**ListView is not showing any effect when i tap a row in ListView i want to show some effect or any colour etc like in iOS when we select or tap on a row in i am using custom view and a custom adapter for ListView and infalting a custom view**

**here i am creating a custom adapter with custom view**

```
CustomContactsHomeAdapter customContactsAdapter = new CustomContactsHomeAdapter(HomeView.this, R.layout.custom_contact_cell, userBean_home_Search.getData(), 
listView.setAdapter(customContactsAdapter);
```

**And this is my custom adapter**

```
public class CustomContactsHomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserBean_Home.DataBean> {

    public UserBean_Home userBean;
    Context mContext;

    public CustomContactsHomeAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public CustomContactsHomeAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<UserBean_Home.DataBean> need, UserBean_Home abc) {
        super(context, resource , need);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.userBean = abc;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact_cell, null);

            TextView contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            TextView contactDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactAddress);
            ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

            UserBean_Home.DataBean dataBean = userBean.getData().get(position);

            if(dataBean.getR_type().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                contactName.setText(dataBean.getFull_name());
                contactDesc.setText("@"+dataBean.getUser_name());
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(GlobalBean.IMAGES_URL+dataBean.getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .into(profileImage);
            } else {

                contactName.setText(dataBean.getGroup_title());
                contactDesc.setText("@"+dataBean.getGroup_description());
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(GlobalBean.IMAGES_URL+dataBean.getGroup_cover_image())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .into(profileImage);
            }
//            if(dataBean.getUnread_messages().equalsIgnoreCase("0") == false) {
//                TextView undreadMessages = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.undreadMessages);
//                undreadMessages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                undreadMessages.setText(dataBean.getUnread_messages());
//            }
    }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 
   }
```

**and this is ListView   in XML**

```
<ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/listView"
     android:layout_below="@id/L1 />
```

**anyone please ??**

Comment: you want highlight item view when selected Or only selector item item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

> listview.setOnItemClickListener

after setting the adapter  like bellow

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: How does this highlight the selected row?

Comment: i have edited my answer and added this line of code arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Comment: And what will happen when another item is selected? How will it get its original color? And how should this work when an item is selected with a keypress on a keyboard?

Comment: it just highlight another item , if you want to have a list of selected item at the end , i think its better you have a customAdatper (that is what i have done) and have a checkbox to know what is selected or deselected or better you can try SparseBooleanArray (if you dont need to change the item view chose this , its pretty fast) ,and in deselecting you can set it to original color , for physical keypass use  listview.setOnKeyListener

Comment: if you just need to change color when selecting read bellow answer from @Ricardo its cleaner than mine for this situation

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is a selector to be applied to the `ListView` items. Here is an example:

Selector mySelector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed" />

</selector>
```

Item example:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ftaccountrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mySelector" >

    .....

</RelativeLayout>
```